# Cucumber and Capybara keep saying that I have an undefined method called `visit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

I keep getting the error message `undefined method 'visit' (NoMethodError)` when I try to run an example given to me from Instant Cucumber BDD How-to by Wayne Ye. I have lots of gems installed, and I think I have run all the necessary commands on my project folder.

My setup notes for what I have installed are:

```
gem install selenium-cucumber
gem install bundler
gem install cucumber-rails
gem install launchy
gem install database_cleaner
gem install factory_girl_rails
gem install webmock
gem install pickle
gem install spork-rails
gem install nokogiri
gem install ffi
gem install capybara
chdir C:\DevKit
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
gem install json
gem install sqlite3
<project folder>cucumber --init
<project folder>bundler init
<project folder>bundler install
```

The example I am trying to run is from the book and looks like this.

Amazon.features

```
Feature: Shopping in Amazon
As an internet user
I want to search stuff on Amazon
So that I can choose and buy items I like

@javascript
Scenario: Search for baseball gloves
   Given I am on Amazon homepage
   When I enter "baseball glove" in the search box
   And I click "Go" button
   Then I should see a list of results related with Baseball Gloves
```

step_definitions/amazon_search_steps.rb

```
Given /^I am on Amazon homepage$/ do
 visit "http://www.amazon.com"
end

When /^I enter "(.*?)" in the search box$/ do |keywords|
 fill_in "Search", :with => keywords
end

When /^I click "Go" button$/ do
 click_button "Go"
end

Then /^I should see a list of results related with Baseball Gloves/ do
 page.should have_content("#centerBelow")
end
```

When I run this, I get the following error message.

[image: undefined method `visit']

Looking online, the solution appears to be to add the following line to my `spec_helper.rb` file, but I don't know which one, and none of the ones I have tried have worked.

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

**EDIT**: As requested my env.rb file.

Full path is C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\cucumber-rails-1.4.3\features\support\env.rb

```
$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib')
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'aruba/cucumber'
if(ENV['ARUBA_REPORT_DIR'])
  # Override reporting behaviour so we don't document all files, only the ones
  # that have been created after @aruba_report_start (a Time object). This is
  # given a value after the Rails app is generated (see cucumber_rails_steps.rb)
  module Aruba
    module Reporting
      def children(dir)
        children = Dir["#{dir}/*"].sort

        # include
        children = children.select do |child|
          File.directory?(child) ||
          (@aruba_report_start && File.stat(child).mtime > @aruba_report_start)
    end

        # exclude
        children = children.reject do |child|
          child =~ /Gemfile/ ||
          child =~ /\.log$/
        end

        children
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have formatted this question for readability; in this case that mostly meant formatting your examples as code blocks. Clean formatting tends to attract more answers, so hopefully this will help you. In the future, you would benefit from learning this formatting yourself, which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: spec_helper.rb is for RSpec. You're using Cucumber, which is configured in env.rb. Show that file.

Comment: Thank you Dan, still new to StackOverflow. And Dave I have added my env.rb.

Comment: To add some closure to this, I wasn't able to find the correct configuration file that I needed to configure and I ended up abandoning this project.